# Стилизация элемента по идентификатору и классу

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
#text {
    color: black;
    backgroud: green;
}

.danger {
    background: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="text" class="danger">
    Text
</div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что блок принимает стилизацию только по идентификатору, а по классу одновременно с идентификатором не получается.

Comment: Все работает ), просто текст и так по умолчанию черный

Comment: Попробуйте поставить зеленый

Comment: @Kison Дело в том, что стиль danger не применяется к объекту.

Comment: id имеет больший вес нежели класс, поэтому и не применяется

Comment: лучше вообще не использовать `id` в `css`, и подобные проблемы не будут возникать.

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, согласен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы перегрузить свойство background используйте !important для класса
.danger

```
 .danger {
     background: red !important;
 }
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не дописал код до конца. Посмотрите еще раз, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: у меня есть дефолт - text, чтобы не создавать подобные блоки и ограничится написанием лишнего кода, мне нужно создать класс, который должен перебивать фон в дефолте

Comment: Можете добавить в danger !important

Comment: Внес правку в ответ